# Store remember token upon user creation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently the laravel remember token work if you approver it on email.

How can I store it at the same time of creating the user?

**Here's my code**

```
$user = New User;
$user->username = $request->username;
$user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
$user->role = $request->role;
$user->remember_token = '' //I don't know how
$user->save();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember token has nothing to do with creating a user, you should ignore that field. It's used for auhtenticating the user from a cookie Laravel automatically sets, if they choose to remember their login.

```
return URL::signedRoute('users.transactions.show', ['user' => 1, 'transaction' => 1]);
```

This will give you something like:

`my-site.test/users/1/transactions/1?signature=AHNP$£INF$PHWRPWENIRPOIh$£RHDOFHIP`

this link above is only valid for `user 1` and `transaction 1`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207249/discussion-on-answer-by-ozan-kurt-store-remember-token-upon-user-creation).

Comment: @SamuelLiew Move to chat functionality gave errors when I tried.